# Capture the output of `tar_make()`

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I want to set up a pipeline using the `targets` package. I like to store the build information for later inspection in a log file.

The `tar_make` documentation explains the `reporter` argument, so

```
x <- capture.output(tar_make(reporter="timestamp_positives"))
```

seems like the right call to me. However, this includes warning messages without timestamp, like

```
#Warnmeldungen:
#1: Paket 'targets' wurde unter R Version 4.2.3 erstellt 
#2: Paket 'tarchetypes' wurde unter R Version 4.2.3 erstellt
```

and also progress characters like `-\|/`. So is there a smart way to log the output of  `tar_make`?